# How to embed multiple glyphs

Tags: css, svg, glyph

I have the following glyph (on glyph made out of few) generated by icomoon

```
<glyph unicode="&#xe905;" d="M0 960h1024v-1024h-1024v1024z" />
<glyph unicode="&#xe906;" d="M0 896h320v-320h-320v320z" />
<glyph unicode="&#xe907;" d="M448 896h512v-128h-512v128z" />
<glyph unicode="&#xe908;" d="M448 704h512v-128h-512v128z" />
<glyph unicode="&#xe909;" d="M0 320h320v-320h-320v320z" />
<glyph unicode="&#xe90a;" d="M448 320h512v-128h-512v128z" />
<glyph unicode="&#xe90b;" d="M448 128h512v-128h-512v128z" />
```

the problem is I'd like to embed it within the CSS 'content' property like a one sign for ex.:

```
.some-selector::before {
   content: '\e900'  
}
```

but

```
.some-selector::before {
   content: '\e905\e906\e907\e908\e909\e90a\e90b'  
}
```

won't work - any idea on how to embed it this way?

**EDIT:**

I want to display those as layers - one on another instead like now (one next to other).

Comment: It 'works' - like it displays icon next icon next icon... etc.... but those icons should be one ON another ON another - like creating layers (instead of being displayed one next to other).

Comment: Yeah...you can't do that...you can't merge characters like that. You'd need to layer them on top of one using a different method...perhaps like the font-awesome "stack"

Comment: I did use icomoon but it did generate few paths (which require multiple CSS selectors), do you have any tool in mind?

Comment: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked